# Actionscript Text field's text not showing?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've set a variable

```
var score:Number = 0;
```

and I have another variable for the score object

```
public var _score:TextField;
```

Though, when I try and edit _score's text, it turns blank. I've tried two things, but both have the same result.

```
_score.text = String(score);
```

nor

```
_score.text = score.toString();
```

have worked, the text ends up going blank, unless I make score equal to 0. Why's this happening?

Comment: Do you have 0-9 embedded in the font?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure, though that is most likely the cause. I didn't think about that.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a font embedding problem. i hope you didn't embed your font which  you are using on that textfield.